# Unable to get data from google finance using pandas web data reader: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Error loading data for SPY from google finance using the Pandas web datareader:

`import pandas_datareader.data as web
dfSPY = web.DataReader('SPY', 'google', start_date, end_date)`

> File "/home/user/Projects/pmb/dataaccess.py", line 63, in import_data
>           dfSPY = web.DataReader('SPY', 'google', start_date, end_date)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/quant35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader-0.5.0-py3.5.egg/pandas_datareader/data.py",
>   line 137, in DataReader
>           session=session).read()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/quant35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader-0.5.0-py3.5.egg/pandas_datareader/base.py",
>   line 181, in read
>           params=self._get_params(self.symbols))   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/quant35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader-0.5.0-py3.5.egg/pandas_datareader/base.py",
>   line 79, in _read_one_data
>           out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/quant35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader-0.5.0-py3.5.egg/pandas_datareader/base.py",
>   line 98, in _read_url_as_StringIO
>           out.write(bytes_to_str(text))   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/quant35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/**init**.py",
>   line 73, in bytes_to_str
>           return b.decode(encoding or 'utf-8')
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position
>   34539: invalid
>   continuation byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue in you can see it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/424

This is how i solved based on the comments from github:

Check if GoogleDailyReader.url() in pandas_datareader/google/daily.py returns 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical'.
If so, change it to 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical'.
(www -> finance)
The return value of GoogleDailyReader.url() was 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical' when I downloaded pandas-datareader in PyCharm yesterday. I don't know why.

Test it with:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
c = pdr.google.daily.GoogleDailyReader()

c.url
# http://www.google.com/finance/historical'

pdr.__version__
# '0.5.0'
```

Comment: Note that "change it to" means to open `pandas_datareader/google/daily.py` in your `dist-packages` folder (in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/` or similar), possibly as root, and modify the source code.